# Str matching and readlines

Tags: python, string

I need a script that reads all files in a directory and searches for a keyword in a list of strings. If the keyword is present in the file, then the filename is saved onto a list. Problem is, I am getting sometimes duplicated name files as my files all have 2 lines (1 for title and other for an abstract) and I am searching once in each line - I want to search once for all lines.

This is the code I have as now:

```
papers = []
files = []
for file in glob.glob("*.txt"):
    with open(file) as f:
        files.append(file)
        for line in f:
            for keyword in keywords:
                if keyword in line:  # search for string
                    print 'found ' + keyword + ' in file %s' % file
                    papers.append(file)
    f.close()
```

Note: I am aware of list(set(papers)) for eliminating duplicates, but that only works for what I need when I'm only searching for one keyword.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: You can use a set rather than a list for files. It will not hold any dupplictes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can make a variable to check if you've found a match and add a `break` statement to the end of your `if` statement. When the condition is met, set the variable to `True` and break out of the loop.

Also you don't need `f.close()` since you are using the `with` statement.

For example:

```
papers = []
files = []
for file in glob.glob("*.txt"):
    with open(file) as f:
        files.append(file)
        found_keyword = False
        for line in f:
            for keyword in keywords:
                if keyword in line:  # search for string
                    print 'found ' + keyword + ' in file %s' % file
                    papers.append(file)
                    found_keyword = True
                    break # break out of keyword loop
            if found_keyword:
                break # break out of line loop
```

---

Comment: @roganjosh you're right, I want to get out of that loop if I find the keyword :)

Comment: Swap the two inner loops. Then break out of the inner one if found.

Comment: I misunderstood originally- I have updated the code. I hope this is what you want.